# mlcp export with document_selector

Tags: xquery, marklogic, mlcp

I have the following XQuery command to retrive documents on the qconsole

```
declare namespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
(/record[@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation eq 'http://foobar.xsd']);
```

and I try to export the data through mlcp but I got syntax error.

```
mlcp.sh export -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -port 8000 -username ####-password ####### \
  -mode local -output_file_path ./mlcp_export -database ##### \
  -path_namespace 'xsi,http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' \
  -document_selector '/record[@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation eq 'http://foobar.xsd']'
23/08/15 17:41:09 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Error getting input splits: 
23/08/15 17:41:09 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Colon_, expecting Comma_ or Rbrack_ or SemiColon_
```

Can someone show me where I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use double quote in the predicate resolved the syntax error.

Comment: The problem is not in fact your XQuery syntax, it is the fact that the command line requires certain characters to be escaped.